# What does it mean to say that $G$ has a 'canonical topological generator' $\text{Frob}_{L/K}$?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field, galois-cohomology

$G$ is $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ where $L$ is unramified extension (could be infinite) of a local field $K$.

What does it mean to say that $G$ has a 'canonical topological generator' $\text{Frob}_{L/K}$?

Does topological generator mean that the element $\text{Frob}_{L/K} $ generate dense subgroup of $G$? (So Galois group of infinite unramified extension need not be cyclic?)

I know that Galois group of finite unramified extension is cyclic and so there is a way to define Frobenius element using that of the residue fields.

Any help is appreciated. Please explain in what sense the generator is canonical. Feel free to give any reference.

Comment: If $\mathbb F_L, \mathbb F_K$ denote the residue fields, there is a canonical isomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\to \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_L/\mathbb F_K)$. The fact that this is an isomorphism is equivalent to the fact that $L/K$ is unramified. On the right hand side there is a canonical topological generator: the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^{|\mathbb F_K|}$. Since this isomorphism is canonical and the Frobenius map is canonical on the RHS, the Frobenius element is canonical. A topological generator is exactly what you said: an element that generates a dense subgroup.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Sorry, but I don't see why $F_L$ should be finite. I know that finite separable extensions of Local fields (with non-archimedian discrete absolute value) are Local as the discrete absolute value extends uniquely and the extension is complete in this exteneded absolute value. For infinite extensions though there is unique extension, but it may not be complete.

Comment: @Mathmo123 For unramified extensions, in particular, we have bijective correspondence between finite extensions of residue field and finite unramified extensions of the local field.

Comment: $\mathbb F_L$ will never be finite if $L$ is infinite and unramified, but that doesn't matter. $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is an inverse limit of Galois groups of finite extensions. which are canonically isomorphic to Galois groups of finite extensions of $\mathbb F_K$. For each of these extensions we can define the canonical Frobenius element as I described. These elements are compatible with the inverse limit.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you. I get it now. I was confused by the notation. I think it boils down to showing that in $\varprojlim _n \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z $, with discrete topology on $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z $, has a topological generator - $(1+n \mathbb Z)$. How do I do this?

Comment: It comes down to unwinding the definitions. The topological generator is the element that maps to $1$ modulo $n$ for every $n$. The subgroup $\cong \mathbb Z$ it generates surjects onto every $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ by construction. If $x$ is an arbitrary element, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, you can find $m\in\mathbb Z$ such that $m\equiv x\mod n$ for all $n\le N$ for arbitrary $N$ (the compatibility in the inverse limit shows that this system of equations has a solution). So any open neighbourhood of $x$ contains a multiple of the generator.

Comment: @Mathmo123 yes! I think even the following $m$ works: choose $m$ such that $m  = x \ \text{mod } (2.3.4 \cdots N)$